# rubyのinline if のscopeについて

Tags: ruby

以下のrubyのコードについて、`result1`は出力できるのに`result2`は出力できないのはなぜですか?

```
if result1 = 'hoge'
  puts "result1 is #{result1}"
end

puts "result2 is #{result2}" if result2 = 'hoge'
```

---

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]
$ ruby sample.rb
sample.rb:1: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
sample.rb:5: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
result1 is hoge
Traceback (most recent call last):
sample.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `result2' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  result1
```

Comment: [Modifier if and unless](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless) に説明があります。`p a if a = 0.zero? This raises the NameError "undefined local variable or method 'a'". When ruby parses ...`

Comment: 「then later it sees the assignment to a in the “test” expression and marks a as a local variable. 」つまり`a`はif blockのscope内で定義されてifの左側はif blockの外だから`a`は存在しない、ということですかね?回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@metropolis さんが示してくれているリンク](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless)に、答えは書いてありますが、リンクは回答としてはあまり適切ではないので、まとめてみます。

似たような if 文での処理を見てみると、次のようになっています。

```
result2 = :foo
puts result2 if result2 = :hoge
# => hoge

0 if result3 = :fuga
puts result3
# => fuga
```

結論として言えることは、今回問題になっている undefined local variable は、 if/unless modifier clause の中で初めて変数を定義し、かつ、その定義される変数を本文において利用していた場合に発生する様子です。

このことの説明は、上記のリンクから辿れますが、説明してみると、 ruby のインタプリタの動作として、 if/unless modifier clause を処理するときに、

1. 最初に変数が bind している変数メタデータストアを、(おそらくその1文で変数が表われた順に)特定し
2. 次に if の中身を評価し
3. 条件を見たしていることが分かれば本文を実行する

という処理をしている様子です。

問題は、上記のような処理を行った場合、 if/unless modifier clause 付きの文であると、その条件式の中で変数が定義されることになったとしても、最初に本文 result2 の変数出現に対しては変数が存在しないとして 1 のプロセスで処理されてしまっているため、本文が実行される段階になった際には、そんな名前の変数は存在しなかった例外を生成してしまう様子です。

結論から言えるのは、 modifier if clause の中で代入は行わない方が無難だな、と思った次第です。

Comment: なるほど、「When ruby parses this expression it first encounters a as a method call in the “then” expression」とあるのでこの時点でifの左側が実行されたら`NameError`は発生することが決まっているんですね。それでif式がtrueだとその中で変数を定義していても`NameError`が発生すると。よくわかりました。ありがとう御座います。

Comment: @IsukeFUJIYAMA  お役にたてたら何よりです。もしこの回答で質問が解決した場合は[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をお願いできますでしょうか。システム的に、問題が解決済みであることを示すことができます。